# Django Rest Framework: other URLs overwritten when including default router

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a directory as follows

```
manage.py
base_app/
    urls.py
    settings.py
    etc...
app1/
    urls.py
    models.py
    etc...
```

My API routes seem to be overwritten, when I include `app1/urls.py` in my `base_app`. For instance, in `base_app/urls.py`, if I have the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    url(r'^schema/$', schema_view),
]
```

Then my schema lists all of the rest-auth API endpoints. Yet when I include the API endpoints from `app1`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('app1.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    url(r'^schema/$', schema_view),
]
```

Then I lose the `rest-auth` endpoints and end up with only `app1`'s endpoints. I think the issue is either in how I'm setting up `app1`'s `urls.py` or with how I am screwing with the namespace improperly in `base_app/urls.py`.

`app1/urls.py` appears as follows (imports not included):

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'app1', views.App1ViewSet, base_name="app1")

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

How do I properly separate the namespace between `rest-auth`'s and `app1`'s APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made all your URLs to resolve to `app1.urls` by putting it at first and matching `^` (matches start of a string, which essentially would be any string).

Move your `app1` URLs at last to make it a *catch-all*:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    url(r'^schema/$', schema_view),
    url(r'^', include('app1.urls')),
]
```

A better solution would be to put the starting URL in the root URL patterns so that when you have multiple apps, all are namespaced based on the start as far as the URLs are concerned:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    ...
    ...
]
```

Then you can omit the starting part in your `app1` url definitions i.e. use the part after `/app1/` e.g.:

```
router.register(r'foobar/$', views.App1FooBar)  # resolves to `/app1/foobar/`
```

---

FWIW, on a supported version you should be using `path` to match URLs instead of Regex matching (which is still supported by `path_re` FWIW).

Comment: I agree with your first comment, but the proposed solution does not work. I don't think that its advisable either. Should I add another app like `app2`, then I'll run into the same problem.

Comment: @nonamorando Updated answer. If it does not work, please add the complete error message to your question.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I'll mark your answer correct. It ended up that my my schema wasn't showing all the routes at the time. Using `coreapi`, I was able to list everything fine. I may have been incorrect on my first comment as well.